# Internal 500 server error in Codeigniter while using JOIN query Builder

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to perform join on two table in codeigniter

Table 1: (registered_cname)
roll_no(int),name(varchar);

Table 2: (student_registered)
roll_no(int),status(varchar),company_name(varchar)

Query Code:

```
$this->db->select($table.'.roll_no,student_placement.stud_name,student_placement.status,student_placement.company_name');

$this->db->from($table);

$this->db->join('student_placement', $table.'.roll_no = student_placement.roll_no');

$this->db->where_in('student_placement.status',$dept);

$this->db->get();
```

Comment: please read the tag description before using it

Answer (score 1):

To debug this you need to examine and test the generated SQL.

You can do so by adding the following to the end of your SQL...

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); // DEBUG
```

And you might need to add in an exit() to trap it depending upon your code.

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); // DEBUG
exit();
```

And look at the SQL and even copy and paste it into your SQL Tool like phpmyadmin and see what happens.

That will give you an indication of what isn't correct.

So you don't have DEBUG code appearing and cant remember where it is, you can modify the exit to be ( and this is only a suggestion) ...

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); // DEBUG
exit(__FILE__ .' '.__LINE__);
```

There are also `__METHOD__` and `__CLASS__` magic constants you can use as well, if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Not able to see any query, as i am passing form data using ajax. I have also put the alert in ajax success for the server response. But no statements seen.

Comment: The query is giving results in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Well if $this-db->last_query() is giving you a result which works in phpmyadmin, that means that your code up to that point isn't the cause and your problem lies elsewhere.